# How to fix undefined in angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

*I'm developing an API to register users and after succesfuly registering it should direct them to the admin dashboard board but am getting this pop up window telling me that localhost:4200 says undefined, tried several solution but am still stuck but all the backeend works fine on postman*

here are my codes

*Here is my login.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth: AuthService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  loginUser(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault()
    const target = event.target
    const email= target.querySelector('#email').value
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value


    this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password).subscribe(data => { 
      if(data.success)
      {
        //redirect the person to admin page
        this.router.navigate(['admindashboard'])
        this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)


      }
      else
      {
        window.alert(data.message);
      }

    });
    console.log(email, password)
  }

}
```

**Here is the auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface myData
{
  success:boolean,
  message: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  uri : String = 'http://localhost:4000';

  private loggedInStatus = false
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setLoggedIn(value: boolean)
  {
  this.loggedInStatus = value
  }

  get isLoggedIn()
  {
    return this.loggedInStatus
  }


  getUserDetails(email: String,password:String){

    //post these details to the database
    return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/auth`,{ email,password });
  }


}
```

> *on Chrome am getting a pop up window saying localhost:4200 undefined*
>
> *iat: 1571218802, exp: 1571218862, token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1Z…g2Mn0.8KN8c_K0XdGno24tKwysZaBpM6PcGlXMs3foWHhVnac"}exp:
>   1571218862iat: 1571218802token:
>   "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZGE2Yzg0Mzk5NTJkZTA3ZTM2NDVhZjIiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imp1bWFqdW1hQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJHFrRm85WktDRWRCaHZkTnFpOVA1V2VIT2FuSXJ4MXVrcWN1dWFDYzMvR3lLQ1poaVpLek02IiwiX192IjowLCJpYXQiOjE1NzEyMTg4MDIsImV4cCI6MTU3MTIxODg2Mn0.8KN8c_K0XdGno24tKwysZaBpM6PcGlXMs3foWHhVnac"**proto**:
>   constructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ
>   hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable:
>   ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ
>   ()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()**defineGetter**: ƒ
>   **defineGetter**()**defineSetter**: ƒ **defineSetter**()**lookupGetter**: ƒ **lookupGetter**()**lookupSetter**: ƒ **lookupSetter**()get **proto**: ƒ **proto**()set **proto**: ƒ **proto**()arguments: (...)caller:
>   (...)length: 1name: "set **proto**"**proto**: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]:
>   Scopes[0]*

Comment: `data.message` is `undefined` print ands check whether `data` has some values

Comment: @Subburaj data comes from the subscribe function or please may you elaborate more

Comment: `window.alert(data.message);` . Above this line do `console.log(data)` and see what its printing

Comment: Tell us what this results:
this.Auth.getUserDetails(email, password).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);

Comment: i get a token and its a expring time i have posted it up there

Comment: @Kyle Mutta So you data doesn't have `success` key so it will got into `else condition` here also your data doesn't have `message` so its throwing `undefined`

Comment: show me how to solve it please am to submit it tommororw @Subburaj

Comment: you can change your if statement like this ro redirect:
 if(data.token)

Comment: thanks at @SuleymanSah the problem is i had to add token in my interface myData the it works fine now thank you